# Android LinearLayout: Give the first element remaing width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve the following layout for 2 elements in a LinearLayout:

[image]

So to sum up:
- The second element should be allowed to fill as much as it needs
- The first element should be shortened down (textview ending on "...") if it is necessary.
- On bigger devices, both elements should be visible (if possible of course) and left aligned.

So here is my solution so far:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/filter_topbar_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lines="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/filter_uppercase_colon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/category_spinner"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sorting_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/sorting_uppercase_colon" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sort_spinner"
            style="@style/spinner"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            tools:entries="@array/sorting_options"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result of my current solution, is the opposite of what I want. Here the first element takes the width that it needs while the second one is pushed away to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first `LinearLayout` as

```
    android:id="@+id/filter_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

And the second `LinearLayout` as

```
    android:id="@+id/sorting_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply... However, I just tested this solution out on a tablet and now the second linearlayout (with weight = 0) is aligned to the right and the first is aligned to the left ( at least that's what it looks like when testing). I need them to aligned left at all times like described in the question (but I guess this could be misunderstood). Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: then you need to provide different xml for tablets as per my knowledge. And make changes probably with wrap_content or by dividing width with width=0 and weight=0.x for respective components. Afterall your question was confusing. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use ellipsize property of textview like

`android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this two properties in your text view

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```